# Javascript - In Promise, resolve function passes a value as a parameter. but what is going on if resolve stands alone?

Tags: javascript, promise, geolocation

I have a question about resolve funciton in Promise.

I understood 'resolve' in Promise as a container passes promise to the next 'then()'.
Like,

```
const something =()=>{return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => { resolve ('hi') } );

something.then( (data) =>{ console.log(data) } )
```

It would log ('hi') becuase 'hi' was passed to the following 'then' by embraced by resolve.
Since I have seen similar cases as above, I thought that resolve is something passes Promise object to the followings.

However, recently I ran into a code example as below.

```
const getcurrentLoc = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve)
    })
}
```

Since I need to pass the coordinate value,
I was expecting that I had write the code as below.

```
const getcurrentLoc = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition())
    })
}
```

However it didn't work out.
What did I misunderstand about 'resolve'?

Comment: Does navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition return a Promise?

Comment: @richytong No, it doesn't spit out Promise.

Comment: When do you pass in the coordinate values?

Comment: @richytong OMG, Aha! moment just came to me . Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What did I misunderstand about 'resolve'?

Your misunderstanding seems to be more about `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

It returns `undefined` so `resolve(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition())` is the same as `resolve(undefined)`.

The first argument it accepts is a *function* (`resolve` is a function). `getCurrentPosition` calls the function in the first argument with a coordinates object.

So you get `resolve(the_coordinates_object)`.

Comment: Oh my god!!!!! Yes right!! I totally missed that part!! thank you so much! Now it became super crystal Clear